# Intuition behind theta function L-series correspondence

Tags: dirichlet-series, theta-functions, mellin-transform

I know that we can analytically continue $L$-series by taking the Mellin transform of a sutiable theta function. Technically we need a transformation law for the theta function at $0$ and $\infty$ as well and then we need to symmetrize the result as much as possible. In any case, for say $\zeta(s)$, a Diricihlet $L$-series $L(s,\chi)$, and the $L$-series $L(s,f)$ for a level $1$ modular form $f$, we have the following correspondences:

\begin{align*}
      \zeta(s) &\longleftrightarrow \omega(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1}e^{-\pi n^{2}x} \longleftrightarrow \vartheta(s) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-\pi n^{2}s} \\
      L(s,\chi) &\longleftrightarrow \omega_{\chi}(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1}\chi(n)n^{\delta_{\chi}}e^{-\pi n^{2}x} \longleftrightarrow \vartheta_{\chi}(s) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\chi(n)n^{\delta_{\chi}}e^{-\pi n^{2}s} \\
      L(s,f) &\longleftrightarrow f(iy) = \sum_{n \ge 1}a(n)e^{-\pi ny},
\end{align*}
here $\delta_{\chi} = 0,1$ depending on if $\chi$ is even or odd and $a(n)$ is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$.

I'm curious if there is good intution for why the first two theta functions $\omega$ and $\omega_{\chi}$ are the **right** ones to look at (beyond the change of variables trick Riemann did with $\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$ for $\zeta(s)$ and then augmenting the argument for $L(s,\chi)$). For a modular form, $f(iy)$ seems like the natural thing to consider since it will immeditely have a transformation law coming from the modularity of $f$ and the coefficients of the series literally match thoes of the $L$-series. This is also the same for $\omega$ but not for $\omega_{\chi}$ if $\chi$ is odd. We also have the additional issue of $n^{2}$ in the exponenet rather than $n$. If I had to guess, the diference in $n^{2}$ vs $n$ comes from that $L(s,f)$ has a degree $2$ Euler product so there will be two local factors at infinity and so the Gamma function you get out of the Mellin transform must be of the form $\Gamma(s)$ rather than $\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$. So you can guess this bit from the Euler product.

For more general $L$-series than those I've mentioned above is there a way to "know" what the theta function will be? Or is this part of the difficult work + experience?

Comment: Please give specific examples. Your $\,\omega(x)\,$ is **not** a theta function unless summed over all integer $\,n.\,$

Comment: I made an edit if this helps you. The first two cases have associated functions that are summed over a lattice since you use Poisson summation to deduce the corresponding transformation laws but the third case does not since the transformation law is geometric in nature. In any case, I've been told its ok to refer to all of these as theta functions but maybe that's not true/or in best interests.